# L'Hospital Rule With Exponents - $ \tan x/x $

Tags: calculus

given the following limit:

$$ \lim _ {x \to 0 } \left (\frac{\tan x } {x}  \right ) ^{1/x^2}\;, $$

is there any simple way to calculate it ?

I have tried writing it as $e^ {\ln (\dots)} $ , but it doesn't give me anything [ and I did l'Hospital on the limit I received... ]

can someone help me with this?

thanks a lot !

Comment: Rewriting as $e^{\ln ...}$ is a good idea. Maybe you should apply l'Hospital it twice.

Comment: applying it twice also doesn't help ... So my guess is that there is some other way to do it .

Comment: There is some other way to do it. Do you know Taylor expansion?

Comment: Yes, but I am pretty sure we need to do it with l'Hospital
Is there any trick to solve it with l'Hospital ?

Thanks !

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1770823/how-to-find-lim-limits-x-to-0-left-frac-tan-x-x-right-frac1x

Answer (score 5):

If you know Taylor expansion, you know that
$$\tan x = x + \frac{x^3}{3}+ \mathcal{O}(x^5)$$
where the big-Oh denotes a term which scales like $x^5$ for $x\to 0$.
Thus, $$\frac{\tan x}{x} = 1 + \frac{x^2}{3} + \mathcal{O}(x^4).$$
The expansion of the logarithm around $1$ reads
$$ \ln (1+y) = y + \mathcal{O}(y^2).$$
Letting $1+y=\tan x/x =1+ x^2/3 + \mathcal{O}(x^4)$, we obtain
$$ \ln \left(\frac{\tan x}x \right) =  \frac{x^2}3 + \mathcal{O}(x^4).$$
Now,
$$ \frac1 {x^2} \ln \left(\frac{\tan x}x \right) = \frac13 + \mathcal{O}(x^2).$$
And thus $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac1 {x^2} \ln \left(\frac{\tan x}x \right) = \frac13.$$

With that you can easily show that 
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac{\tan x}x\right) ^{x^{-2}} = \sqrt[3]{e}.$$

Comment: just one thing: in your 9th line, you wrote $ ln (1+\frac{x^2 }{3} +O(x^4) $ = $\frac{x^2 }{3} +O(x^4) $ . 
Shouldn't you also change something in the big-o ? 

thanks!@

Comment: i.e.- your $y$ is $ y = \frac{x^2}{3} +O(x^4 ) $ , and you are looking at $ ln(1+y)$

Comment: The next term in the expansion of $\ln (1+y)= x^2/3+ ...$ comes from the first order term of $O(x^4)$ and the second order term of $x^2/3$ both of which are of order $O(x^4)$. (hope this is understandable)

Comment: Soryy, but I couldn't understand ...
Shouldn't you have $O(x^8)$ after substituting?

Comment: Note that already without the $O(x^4)$ term in $y$ that is with $y= 1+ x^2/3$ we have $\log(y) =x^2/3 - x^4/18 + \dots = x^2/3 + O(x^4)$.

Comment: got it ! thanks !!!

Answer (score 4):

$$ \lim _ {x \to 0 } \left (\frac{\tan x } {x}  \right ) ^{1/x^2}=\lim_{x\to 0}\left(1+\left({\frac{\tan x-x}{x}}\right)\right)^{{x\over\tan x-x}{\tan x-x\over x^3}}=e^{\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan x-x}{x^3}}$$

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan x-x}{x^3}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{{1\over \cos^2x}-1}{3x^2}={1\over 3}\lim_{x\to 0}\left({\tan x\over x}\right)^2={1\over 3}$$
$$ \lim _ {x \to 0 } \left (\frac{\tan x } {x}  \right ) ^{1/x^2}=e^{1/3}$$

Comment: How good do you see my approach, Adi?:)

Answer (score 3):

Use this fact as well:

> If $\lim\limits_{x\to{+\infty}} f(x)^{g(x)}$ be as $1^{+\infty}$, which is an indeterminate form, then we have this fact that: $$\lim_{x\to{+\infty}} f(x)^{g(x)}=e^{\lim\limits_{x\to +\infty}\big(f(x)-1\big)g(x)}$$

Here we have $$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\exp\left(\frac{\tan(x)-x}{x^3}\right)=\exp(1/3)$$

Comment: Helpful to know! +1

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks ;-)

Comment: I really like how you contribute, giving diverse ways of looking at problems, and doing so in a helpful, nudging, and instructive way.  Students so often fall into the "trap" of thinking there is only one correct answer, or one way of doing things, etc...so you help bring "creativity" to math!

Comment: Thanks for saying so. It is very kind of you @amWhy. :-)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do it with l'Hospital's rule. It takes 4 applications, but it does work! Do the exponential transformation, and continue simplifying with l'Hospital's rule and limits until you get:

$$ \exp\left(-\frac{\left(2 \left(\lim_{x\rightarrow0} \cos\left(2 x\right)\right)\right)}{\left(\lim_{x\rightarrow0} \left(\left(4 x^2-6\right) \cos\left(2 x\right)+12 x \sin\left(2 x\right)\right)\right)}\right) $$

Use a bunch of limit rules (quotient, continuity, sum, product, polynomial, in that order), in order to get:
$$ \exp\left(-\frac{\left(2 \cos\left(\lim_{x\rightarrow0} 2 x\right)\right)}{\left(12 \left(\lim_{x\rightarrow0} x\right) \left(\lim_{x\rightarrow0} \sin\left(2 x\right)\right)-6 \cos\left(\lim_{x\rightarrow0} 2 x\right)\right)}\right) $$

Just evaluate all the limits now:
$$ \exp\left(\frac{1}{3}\right) $$

Tedious, but certainly doable! I would recommend Fabian's solution instead, 4 applications of Hospital's, although possible, is something you want to avoid if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$y=\left (\frac{\tan x } {x}  \right ) ^{1/x^2}$$

So, $$\ln y=\frac{\ln \tan x -\ln x}{x^2}$$

Then $$\lim_{x\to 0}\ln y=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln \tan x -\ln x}{x^2}\left(\frac 00\right)$$ as $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac {\tan x}x=1$

Applying L'Hospital's Rule: ,  $$\lim_{x\to 0}\ln y=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac2{\sin2x}-\frac1x}{2x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2x-\sin2x}{2x^2\sin2x}\left(\frac 00\right)$$

$$=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2-2\cos2x}{4x\sin2x+4x^2\cos 2x}\left(\frac 00\right)$$ (applying L'Hospital's Rule)

$$=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{4\sin2x}{4\sin2x+8x\cos2x+8x\cos 2x-8x^2\sin2x}\left(\frac 00\right)$$ (applying L'Hospital's Rule)

$$=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{8\cos2x}{8\cos2x+2(8\cos2x-16x\sin2x)-16x\sin2x-16x^2\cos2x}\left(\frac 00\right)$$ (applying L'Hospital's Rule)

$$=\frac8{8+2\cdot8}=\frac13$$

Comment: wow ! great ! thanks  a lot !!!

Comment: @theMissingIngredient, my pleasure. I think the problem is best solved by Fabian's way if 'L'Hospital's Rule' is not mentioned.