# Find $\lim_{x \to 0} (\frac{\tan(x)}{x})^{\frac{1}{x}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

> Find $$\lim_{x \to 0} (\frac{\tan(x)}{x})^{\frac{1}{x}}$$

My first idea to solve this was to try to evaluate it and then apply the L'Hospital's rule. This is what I managed to achieve:
$$\left(\frac{\tan(x)}{x}\right)^\frac{1}{x}=e^{\frac{1}{x}\ln\left(\frac {\tan(x)}x \right)} $$
However, this is problematic, because the L'Hospital's rule is not applicable in the exponent, therefore my transformation was not a good shot. What transformation should I apply to get the desired form?

Comment: It's a good start, let's now use Taylor series for tanx and then logx.

Comment: @gimusi Is it possible to solve this without the Taylor series?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Find $ \lim\limits_{x\to 0} \left(\frac {\tan x }{x} \right)^{\frac{1}{x^2}}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1770823/how-to-find-lim-limits-x-to-0-left-frac-tan-x-x-right-frac1x)

Comment: @GuyFsone Not a duplicate, that other question is interesting.

Comment: Note that $\frac{\tan(x) -  x}{x^3}\to \frac{1}{3}$ by l'Hospital rule.

Comment: @Aemilius I'm not sure you can avoid at all some expansion, Taylor series is not so complex to learn, teh most important issue is to get confident with the algebraic rules to handle little-o correctly.

Comment: @gimusi Yes you can prove the result using only l'Hospital's rule.

Comment: @Gribouillis ok but l'Hospital is equivalent to an expansion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us prove the result by using only l'Hospital's rule. We have

$${\left(\frac{\tan  \left(x\right)}{x}\right)}^{\frac{1}{x}} = \exp  \left(\frac{\ln \left|\tan  \left(x\right)\right|-\ln  \left|x\right|}{x}\right) := \exp  \left(\frac{f \left(x\right)}{x}\right)$$

Note that $f \left(0\right) = 0$ and

$${f'} \left(x\right) = \frac{1}{\tan  \left(x\right)} \left(1+{\tan }^{2} \left(x\right)\right)-\frac{1}{x} = \tan  \left(x\right)-x \left(\frac{x}{\tan  \left(x\right)}\right) \left(\frac{\tan  x-x}{{x}^{3}}\right)$$

By l'Hospital rule we have

$$
 \frac{\tan  \left(x\right)}{{x}} \mathop{\longrightarrow}\limits_{x \rightarrow  0} 1,
\qquad  \frac{\tan  \left(x\right)-x}{{x}^{3}} \mathop{\longrightarrow}\limits_{x \rightarrow  0} \frac{1}{3}$$

it follows that ${f'} \left(x\right) \mathop{\longrightarrow}\limits_{x \rightarrow  0} 0$, hence applying again
l'Hospital's rule we get

$$\frac{f \left(x\right)}{x} \mathop{\longrightarrow}\limits_{x \rightarrow  0} 0 \quad  \Longrightarrow  \quad  {\left(\frac{\tan  \left(x\right)}{x}\right)}^{\frac{1}{x}} \mathop{\longrightarrow}\limits_{x \rightarrow  0} 1$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\tan x=x+O(x^3)$$
$$\frac{\tan x}x=1+O(x^2)$$
$$\ln\frac{\tan x}x=O(x^2)$$
$$\ln\left[\left(\frac{\tan x}x\right)^{1/x}\right]=\frac1x\ln\frac{\tan x}x=O(x)$$
etc.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{1}{x}\ln\left(\dfrac{\tan x}{x}\right)&=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{1}{x}\ln\left(\dfrac{x+\dfrac{1}{3}x^{3}+\cdots}{x}\right)\\
&=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{1}{x}\ln\left(1+\dfrac{1}{3}x^{2}+\cdots\right)\\
&=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{1}{x}\left(\dfrac{1}{3}x^{2}-\dfrac{1}{2}\left(\dfrac{1}{3}x^{3}\right)^{2}+\cdots\right)\\
&=0.
\end{align*}
So the limit is $e^{0}=1$.

Answer (score 1):

### Easy trick

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac{\tan x}{x}\right)^{\frac1{x}}  =\lim_{x\to 0}\exp\left(\frac{1}{x}\ln\left(\frac{\tan x -x}{x}+1\right)\right) \sim \lim_{x\to 0}\exp\left(\frac{x}{3}\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{x^2}{3}\right)}{\frac{x^2}{3}}\right)= \color{blue}{1}$$

Given that $$\tan x -x \sim \frac{x^3}{3}~~~~and ~~~~ \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\ln\left(1+h\right)}{h} = 1$$

Comment: @user284331 thanks edit made

Answer (score 1):

i would write $$\exp\left({\frac{\ln(\tan(x))-\ln(x)}{x}}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

By Taylor's series:

$\tan x=x+\frac{x^3}{3}+o(x^3)$

$\log (1+x)=x+o(x)$

Thus:

$$\left(\frac{\tan x}{x}\right)^\frac{1}{x}=e^{\frac{1}{x}\ln\left(\frac {\tan x }x \right)}=e^{\frac{1}{x}\ln\left(1+\frac{x^2}{3}+o(x^2)\right)}=e^{\frac{x}{3}+o(x)}\to e^0=1$$

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use L'Hospital's rule, I would note that the limit of these two functions are equal:
$\frac{ln(\frac{tanx}{x})}{x}$ and $\frac{(tan^2x+1)x-tanx}{xtanx}$, and then rewrite the second term as $tanx + \frac{x-tanx}{xtanx}$, noting that $tanx$ is eliminated. It remains to find $\frac{x-tanx}{xtanx}$. But by applying L'Hospital's rule again, we can see that this is equivalent to $\frac{-tanx}{1+\frac{x}{tanx}(1+tan^2x)}$, which goes to $0$ since $\frac{x}{tanx}$ goes to $1$. So your limit is $e^0$ which is $1$.