# Evaluate the limit $\lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac {\tan x}{x}\right)^{\frac {1}{x}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Evaluate the limit $\lim_{x\to 0} \left(\dfrac {\tan x}{x}\right)^{\dfrac {1}{x}}$

My Attempt:
$$\lim_{x\to 0} A= \lim_{x\to 0} \left(\dfrac {\tan x}{x}\right)^{\dfrac {1}{x}}$$
Taking $\ln$ on both sides,
$$\ln (\lim_{x\to 0} A)=\lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac {1}{x}\cdot \ln\left(\dfrac {\tan x}{x}\right)$$

Comment: Use http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesExpansion.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find $\lim_{x \to 0} (\frac{\tan(x)}{x})^{\frac{1}{x}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2574690/find-lim-x-to-0-frac-tanxx-frac1x) I found it thanks to [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim_%7Bx%5Cto%200%7D%20%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%20%7B%5Ctan%20x%7D%7Bx%7D%5Cright)%5E%7B%5Cfrac%20%7B1%7D%7Bx%7D%7D%24&p=1).