# Find the limit $\lim_{x \to 0}{\left(\frac{\tan x}{x}\right)}^{1/{x^2}}$ using l'Hôpital's Rule.

Tags: calculus, limits

Here is the limit I'm trying to find.

$$\lim_{x \to 0}{\left(\frac{\tan x}{x}\right)}^{1/{x^2}}$$

Now, since it takes an indeterminate form at $x=0$, I'm taking natural logarithm and trying to find the following limit.

$$
\begin{align}
L
& = \lim_{x \to 0}\ln{\bigg(\frac{\tan{x}}{x}\bigg)}^{1/{x^2}} \\
& = \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\ln{\left(\frac{\tan{x}}{x}\right)}}{x^2}
\end{align}
$$

Now, l'Hôpital's Rule cannot be applied here since the numerator
$ f(x)
  = \ln\left({\frac{\tan{x}}{x}}\right)
$
is undefined at $x = 0$. What should be done here?

Comment: The numerator tends to $0$ as $  x \to 0$ so the limit is in $\frac 0 0$ from. L'Hopital's Rule is applicable.

Comment: Use the fact $\ln(\frac{a}{b}) = \ln (a) - \ln (b)$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [L'Hospital Rule With Exponents - $ \tan x/x $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/268243/lhospital-rule-with-exponents-tan-x-x), or [this other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1770823/how-to-find-lim-limits-x-to-0-left-frac-tan-x-x-right-frac1x).

Answer (score 1):

For this type of problem, it is simpler to get the limit using the Maclaurin series of the tangent function and the logarithm function.  Letting $z = 1/x^2$ we can write:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{x^2} \log \bigg( \frac{\tan x}{x} \bigg)
&= \frac{1}{x^2} \Bigg[ \log \tan (x) - \log(x) \Bigg] \\[6pt]
&= \frac{1}{x^2} \Bigg[ \bigg( x + \frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{2 x^5}{15} + \frac{17 x^7}{315} + \cdots \bigg) - \log(x) \Bigg] \\[6pt]
&= \frac{1}{x^2} \log \bigg( 1 + \frac{x^2}{3} + \frac{2 x^4}{15} + \frac{17 x^6}{315} + \cdots \bigg) \\[6pt]
&= z \log \bigg( 1 + \frac{1}{3z} + \frac{2}{15 z^2} + \frac{17}{315 z^3} + \cdots \bigg) \\[6pt]
&= z \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} \bigg( \frac{1}{3z} + \frac{2}{15 z^2} + \frac{17}{315 z^3} + \cdots \bigg)^n  \\[6pt]
&= z \Bigg[ \frac{1}{3z} + O(z^{-2}) \Bigg] \\[6pt]
&= \frac{1}{3} + O(z^{-1}). \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

Taking $x \rightarrow 0$ gives $z \rightarrow \infty$ which gives:

$$\frac{1}{x^2} \cdot \log \bigg( \frac{\tan x}{x} \bigg) 
= \frac{1}{3} + O(z^{-1}) \rightarrow \frac{1}{3},$$

so we have:

$$\bigg( \frac{\tan x}{x} \bigg)^{1/x^2} \rightarrow \exp(1/3) = 1.395612.$$

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$\left(\frac{\tan x}{x}\right)^{\frac1{x^2}}= \left[\left(1+\frac{\tan x-x}{x}\right)^{\frac x{\tan x-x}}\right]^{\frac{\tan x-x}{x^3}}$$

then use $\lim_{x\to 0} (1+x)^{\frac1x}=e$ and l’Hospital for $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\tan x-x}{x^3}$.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from your last step:
\begin{align} L= \lim \limits_{x\to 0} \frac{\tan(x)-x}{x^3}\\ \end{align}
(Notice that $\lim \limits_{x\to 0} \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}= 1$ so $\lim \limits_{x\to 0} \frac{\ln(1+(\frac{\tan(x)}{x}-1))}{\frac{\tan(x)}{x}-1}= 1$). Apply the l'Hôpital's Rule :
\begin{align} L= \lim \limits_{x\to 0} \frac{\sec{^2}(x)-1}{3x^2}= \lim \limits_{x\to 0} \frac{\tan{^2}(x)}{3x^2}= \frac{1}{3}\\ \end{align}

Comment: Please elaborate how $\frac{\ln\left({\frac{\tan{x}}{x}}\right)}{x^2} = \frac{\tan{x}-{x}}{x^3}$.

Comment: Sorry for the shortcut. You can use that substitution to deal with limit problems that involve log functions because taking derivative of them just takes more steps and it might be more complex.

Answer (score 0):

As $x \to 0 , {\tan x \over x} \to 1$ . Therefore , $\ln{\left({\tan x \over x}\right)} \to 0$ .

Therefore , ${{\ln{\left({\tan x \over x}\right)}} \over x^2 }$ is $0 \over 0$ form at $x=0$ , hence l'hopital rule can be applied .

Applying l'hopital rule in $$L= \lim_{x \to 0} {{\ln{\left({\tan x \over x}\right)}} \over x^2 } $$, we get

$$L= \lim_{x \to 0} {{{{\sec^2 x } \over \tan x } - {1 \over x }} \over 2x } = \lim_{x \to 0} {{{x {\sec^2 x }} - \tan x } \over {{2 x^2 }\tan x}}$$

Using $\lim_{x \to 0} {\tan x \over x } = 1 $ we get

$$L = \lim_{x \to 0} {{\sec^2 x -1} \over {2 x {\tan x}}}= \lim_{x \to 0} {{\tan x } \over 2x } = {1 \over 2 }$$

Therefore , $$L= {1 \over 2}$$